# Multiple FormControls in FormGroup - Uncaught Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular, forms

I have a list of rows with two inputs field next to each other in a form group as shown here:
[image]

HTML is here:

```
  <form [formGroup]="measuresForm">
    <div *ngFor="let measure of measures.categories">
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-3 col-xxl-2">
          <button class="w-100 h-100 bg-info border">
            {{ measure.value }}
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-7">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="{{ measure.value }}"
            formControlName="{{ measure.value }}"
            [ngClass]="{
              'form-control': true,
              'is-invalid':
                measuresForm.controls[measure.value].invalid &&
                published
            }"
            (keyup)="updateMeasureValue(measure.value, $any($event.target).value)"
            value="{{ measure.label }}"
          />
          <p *ngIf="published" class="invalid-feedback">Required field</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <input
            type="number"
            id="{{ measure.decimalPrecision }}"
            formControlName="{{ measure.decimalPrecision }}"
            [ngClass]="{
              'form-control': true,
              'is-invalid':
                measuresForm.controls[measure.decimalPrecision].invalid &&
                published
            }"
            value="{{ measure.decimalPrecision }}"
            (input)="updateMeasureDecimalPrecision(measure.value, $any($event.target).value)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

As you can see I have two `formControlName`, one for each set of input fields because they require different validators, and I want to emit an event saying that the form is dirty whenever a change is made in any input field.

Here is typescript code:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() published: boolean;
  @Input() isDirty: boolean;

  @Output() isDirtyChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() labelsValidChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  measures: DimensionWithCategory;
  measuresForm: FormGroup;
  private formControls = [];
  private editCategorySetService =  inject(EditCategorySetService);
  private formBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.measures = this.editCategorySetService.getMeasures();
    for (let measure of this.measures.categories) {
      this.formControls[measure.value] = new FormControl(measure.label, Validators.required);
      this.formControls[measure.decimalPrecision] = new FormControl(measure.decimalPrecision, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]+$"));
    }
    this.measuresForm = this.formBuilder.group(this.formControls);
  }

  updateMeasureValue(value: string, newLabel: string) {
    this.editCategorySetService.updateMeasureLabel(value, newLabel);
    this.isDirtyChange.emit(this.measuresForm.dirty);
    this.labelsValidChange.emit(this.measuresForm.valid);
  }

  updateMeasureDecimalPrecision(value: string, newDecimalPrecision: number) {
    this.editCategorySetService.updateMeasureDecimalPrecision(value, newDecimalPrecision);
    this.isDirtyChange.emit(this.measuresForm.dirty);
  }
}
```

With this code I get the error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute`. How can I get this to work with multiple formControls in one FormGroup? If I just remove one of the formControlNames, then I get no errors, but I also don't get an event emitted when making changes in the input group that has no formControlName.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your HTML form with this one:

```
 <form [formGroup]="measuresForm">
<div *ngFor="let measure of measures.categories">
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-3 col-xxl-2">
      <button class="w-100 h-100 bg-info border">
        {{ measure.value }}
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7">
      <input
        type="text"
        [id]="measure.value"
        [formControlName]="measure.value"
        [ngClass]="{
          'form-control': true,
          'is-invalid':
            measuresForm.controls[measure.value].invalid &&
            published
        }"
        (keyup)="updateMeasureValue(measure.value, $any($event.target).value)"
        value="{{ measure.label }}"
      />
      <p *ngIf="published" class="invalid-feedback">Required field</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <input
        type="number"
        [id]="measure.decimalPrecision"
        [formControlName]="measure.decimalPrecision"
        [ngClass]="{
          'form-control': true,
          'is-invalid':
            measuresForm.controls[measure.decimalPrecision].invalid &&
            published
        }"
        value="{{ measure.decimalPrecision }}"
        (input)="updateMeasureDecimalPrecision(measure.value, $any($event.target).value)"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be working @fabio. Could you explain the logic behind it, just so I understand?

Comment: in your project you are cycling data using *ngFor, for this reason you need to bind with square brackets the attributes id and the fomControlName, pratically you made a syntax error. [id]="measure.value"
        [formControlName]="measure.value" instead id="{{measure.value}}" and formControlName="{{measure.value}}"
 This logic is valid also when you aren't using form fields, remember to use squared brackets for HTML attributes when you need to pass object data or simple proprerites declared in your back code to the HTML